# USB PIC programer

Tags: pic, programmer

I am trying to do a USB pic programer,I searched about that and I found:
1- a simple circuit.
2- software program (UsbPicProg).

this is the circuit:

[image]

My problems :

1-is this circuit and this program enough to got USB programer , I dont wanna buy the components before make sure that at least someone made it or knows it will work.

2-I need USB PIC programer the circuit and the interfacing program if the above all wrong.

thanks for all

Comment: In English the first letter of every sentence is capitalized, the word "I" is capitalized, and multiple thoughts are broken into multiple sentences.  By not following these rules you are making your post annoying to read.  Please fix that, then we can discuss your problem.

Comment: The first google hit for usbpicprog is the website of the project. It might be a good idea to at least cast a glance at that info, and compare their circuit to yours. (Spoiler: the two are not identical.)

Comment: @OlinLathrop- I am just a human :(

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen- yes I did compared them , I just wanna make sure this one will not work

Comment: @Alone: your circuit doesn't even have connections to the chip you want to program...

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen: ok thank you for help ,now what can I do?

Comment: Don't try to excuse sloppiness, just fix it.  Better yet, don't dump something like that on us in the first place.  Also, there is no such word in English as "wanna".

Comment: @Alone: What is your question? You know the circuit you show won't work, and you know where to find working circuits (from usbpicprog, or from Olin's links).

Comment: Unless the PIC18F4550 comes from your supplier with a USB bootloader already on it, you will have a chicken-vs-egg problem, in that you will likely need a pic programmer to program the pic on your pic programmer...

Answer (score 1):

There are many PIC programmers out there, some of which work over USB to the host.  These include my [USBProg](http://www.embedinc.com/products/usbprog) and [LProg](http://www.embedinc.com/products/lprog).  The schematics are available on those pages, so you can build your own if you want to, or use some of the ideas from those designs.

Comment: your links very use full thank you , I thought it will be easy to do a pic programer using USB I made an ATmega 328-pu programer using FTDI and its so simple .